# Laptop Function Key Dysfunctional

Tags: windows-vista, function-keys

My laptop has Windows Vista installed in it. Everytime, I switch on the computer, the function key seems to be enabled automatically. So, when I press i, 5 is displayed and so on and so forth.

Now, I have checked and ensured that Function is key is not locked due to a faulty keyboard or coke spilling on it and suchlike. I am able to get out of it with the following key combination 
Fn + Ctrl + Ins (Num Lk)

However, the next time I switch on my PC, the Function key is automatically enabled. Also, if my computer goes to sleep mode and comes back, it is enabled again.

Anything that I can do to change this behaviour?

Comment: isn't this ironic..

Comment: Make and Model of PC? Please edit your post to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can change "Bootup Numlock" in the Bios?

Comment: But isn't that for ensuring that NumLock is automatically enabled during Boot Sequence. I quite did not understand the relevance to my question here. Can you please clarify? May be there is a relation, but it being a Sunday evening and the Monday looming large, I am not able to see the relavance...

Comment: Because this whole i -> 5 business is a notebook´s way of enabling Numlock...